# How do I select specific text within a cell to format when the table is in the header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to delete and replace the header and footer of around 50 documents, so I'm writing VBA code to change the header and footer.  In the header, I want the logo on the right, and text in two lines centered in the header.  The text in the top line should be formatted differently than the second line.

Here is the code as I have it now - I've only written the code for the first line so far; I wanted to get that to work before adding the code to format the second line.  When it runs - (in break mode) The string specified isn't actually selected - the selection just stays as the contents of the cell, and the formatting is applied to all the header text.

```
Private Sub AddHeaderToRange(rng As Word.Range)
    Dim imgPath As String, myImg As InlineShape, secondLine As String, firstLine As String
    firstLine = "Imagine Southwest Region"
    secondLine = "AZ Social Studies 2020-21"
    imgPath = "C:\Users\Laura.Defibaugh\Pictures\imagine_logo.jpg"


    With rng
        .Tables.Add Range:=rng, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
        With .Tables(1)
            .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
            .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
            .Cell(1, 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(9), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
            .Cell(1, 2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(0.8), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
            .Cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = firstLine & vbCrLf & secondLine
            Set myImg = .Cell(1, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Laura.Defibaugh\Pictures\imagine_logo.jpg")
                With myImg
                    .Width = InchesToPoints(0.8)
                    .Height = InchesToPoints(0.8)
            End With

            .Cell(1, 1).Range.Select

                With Selection.Find
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Text = firstLine
                    .Execute
                End With

                With Selection.Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Size = 20
                End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new document with the required header/footer layout, then use the FormattedText method to replicate that in all the target documents. For example:

```
Sub UpdateDocumentHeadersAndFooters()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim wdDocTgt As Document, wdDocSrc As Document
Dim Sctn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wdDocSrc = ActiveDocument
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
    If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> wdDocSrc.FullName Then
        Set wdDocTgt = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        With wdDocTgt
            For Each Sctn In .Sections
                'For Headers
                For Each HdFt In Sctn.Headers
                    With HdFt
                        If .Exists Then
                            If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
                                .Range.FormattedText = _
                                wdDocSrc.Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.FormattedText
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
                'For footers
                For Each HdFt In Sctn.Footers
                    With HdFt
                        If .Exists Then
                            If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
                                .Range.FormattedText = _
                                wdDocSrc.Sections.First.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.FormattedText
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            Next
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDocSrc = Nothing: Set wdDocTgt = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

As coded, the macro assumes the document you're running the macro from has only one Section, with up to three populated headers and footers (as allowed by Word), and that all headers in the target document are to be updated to match the source document's primary header & footer.

If you only want to update the first Section, change 'For Each Sctn In .Sections' to 'Set Sctn = .Sections.First' and delete the corresponding 'Next'.